# When we point a method by another current method or variable using $this keyword

Tags: php, oop

Sometime I find some way of OOP programming that $this keyword is used to point the current method and which also point another method. i.e. `$this->getView()->render($view, $params, $this)` the live in [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Widget.php#L182). Another example, `$this->view->setVar("postId", $postId);`. I do not know what it is called and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a "fluent interface".

`$this` still only "points" to a single method or property, but that method can return (or a property can hold) a value of any PHP datatype, which includes other objects.

In the first example, the `getView()` method returns an object, which in turn has a method called `render()`; while in the second case, the `view` property holds an object which has a `setvar()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I am new in this concept. Let me google. However, if you good reference to learn that would be helped.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/777/fluent-interfaces-in-php/

Comment: do you want to say that `getView()` method returns an on object which should have the method `render()`, right? But I did not find object `getView()` had the method `render()`.

Comment: What object is returned by the `getView()` method, and what methods does that object have?

Comment: It returns a lot of methods but I did not find `render()`. However, it is core file of Yii2. Not much important to know this things. Just to be confirmed about my understanding that object should have method in this situation, right? `$this->obj()->method()`.

Comment: If the class extends a core Yii class, then that might implement the render() method..... because otherwise it would give a runtime error